# Marketing Cloud Data extension - prevent from sending future email if not double opt-in

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm trying to figure out which system field should I modify in order to prevent Marketing Cloud from sending future email to whoever did not activate their email (Double-opt-in).

In this scenario we're not using the default preference center or profile center but only custom data extensions. Is there a specific system field to be changed (perhaps the 'Status' field in the All Subscribers ?).

The idea is that by default the field is inactive and once the subscriber verifies the email for the first time, the system can start to send emails.

Thanks for any suggestion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I will solve it entirely in your data extension. You can use three fields for this, e.g:

- optinProvided (date)
- doubleOptinProvided (date)
- active (boolean) - defaut: FALSE

You will mark the first field with a timestamp, showing when the individual first signed up, also allowing you to time any reminder emails accordingly.
Second field will be blank, until the double opt-in is confirmed. This activity will also mark the boolean as TRUE

Keep in mind, that you will always have to reference these fields when adding your contacts to a journey or any other commercial send, as the system will not implicitly prevent them from receiving emails.

Alternatively, you can do following:

1. Create the individual in All Subscribers list
2. Set the status in All Subscribers list to Unsubscribed, immediately upon creation
3. Once Double opt-in is confirmed, change the status to Active.

This will prevent any emails with commercial send classification from being sent. Your double opt in email will be sent with transactional classification, not being blocked by the status in All Subs.

You can use SOAP API to [create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_subscriber.htm) and [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_subscriber_attributes_using_the_update_method.htm) records in All Subs.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your answer. I will probably go with the system alternative just because otherwise I'd have to specify, for each Journey the additional opt-in fields. However I do recognise the first solution allows for more control over sending future mail. Appreciate your help.